# Taylor series without expanding factorial in denominator

Tags: differential-equations

A Taylor series is produced with the following code:

```
Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 15}] 

x-x^3/6+x^5/120-x^7/5040+x^9/362880-x^11/39916800+x^13/6227020800-x^15/1307674368000+O(x^16)
```

Is there a simple way to prevent the factorial in each denominator from being evaluated?  That is, I want an answer of the form:

$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
s = Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 15}] // Normal ;
s /. Times[_[a_, b_], c_] :>a (c/Inactive[Factorial][InverseFunction[Gamma][b] - 1])
```

Note:

The above method will not work for any function

This works for any function:

```
s /. Times[a_, Power[_, b_]] :> (a x^b) (b!)/Inactive[Factorial][b]
```

Comment: Quite clever...

Comment: @Algohi: Wow! The one thing I don't understand is the blank underscore in Power[_,b_]. Is that what you do when you don't intend to use what is stored there?

Comment: @David This a pattern matching and yes this is what to do when you don't want to use that part. You can also give it a name and not use it like this: Power[c_,b_]

Answer (score 4):

```
s = Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 15}];

s /. Rational[a_, b_] :>  With[{z = First@ If[Reduce`FactorialInverse[b] === {}, b, 
      Reduce`FactorialInverse[b]]}, a/HoldForm[Factorial[z]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or use `Defer` in place of `HoldForm`.

Comment: Ohh... +1 for reminding me of the faster inverse hidden away in reduce world!

Answer (score 3):

A quick hack, until something better comes along:

```
  s = Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 14}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
getFact[n_] := Module[{z = 2, r}, r = n/z; While[ r != 1, r = r/++z]; z];
s = ReplacePart[s, 3 -> Map[With[{t = Denominator[#]}, If[t == 1, #, 
  With[{z = getFact[t]}, Numerator[#]/HoldForm[Factorial[z]]]]] &, s[[3, All]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For expansion around non-zero:

```
 s = Series[Sin[x], {x, 2, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Although this doesn't quite get the solution in your desired form, it does extract the coefficients in unexpanded factorials.

```
Assuming[n >= 0, SeriesCoefficient[Sin[x], {x, 0, n}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}] // Normal;

Replace[s, Times[Rational[s_, z_], p_] :> 
           Times[s/HoldForm[Factorial[#]] &@InverseFunction[Factorial][z], p], Infinity]
```

$x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}$