# Using Defer with Series

Tags: series-expansion

Has anyone ever used the Defer command with the Series command for example to output the series
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...$$
without the factorials being evaluated.

Comment: As I guess, option of `ComplexityFunction` of function `Simplify` maybe can help.But I cannot figure it out.

Comment: related/possible duplicate Q/A: [Taylor series without expanding factorial in denominator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/74078/125)

Answer (score 4):

```
Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 7}]] /. Rational[t_, 
   a_] :> (t/Defer[#!] &[First[Reduce`FactorialInverse[a]]])
```

> $x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}$

Answer (score 3):

```
f[n_] = Assuming[n >= 0, 
    SeriesCoefficient[Sin[x], {x, 0, n}]] /. {Factorial[x_] :> Defer[x!]};
SeriesData[x, 0, f /@ Range[7], 1, 8, 1] /. (Defer[Factorial[1]] -> 1) // Normal
```

> $x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!}$