# In a power series, how do we keep the $\frac{1}{n!}$ term without simplification for all $x^{n}$?

Tags: series-expansion

I am trying to visualize the Euler numbers coming from the generating function:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq0}E_{n}\frac{x^{n}}{n!} & =\text{sec}(x)+\text{tan}(x)\\
 & =1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+2\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+5\frac{x^{4}}{4!}+16\frac{x^{5}}{5!}+61\frac{x^{6}}{6!}+272\frac{x^{7}}{7!}+1385\frac{x^{8}}{8!}+7936\frac{x^{9}}{9!}\cdots
\end{align*}

But, when treated as usual, `Series[Sec[x] + Tan[x], {x, 0, 9}]` , Mathematica simplifies $\frac{E_{n}}{n!}$ when possible so we cannot identify coefficients neatly.
Should it be enough to multiply $n!$, but

```
n = 9; Take[Range[0, n]!]*Series[Sec[x] + Tan[x], {x, 0, n}]
```

generates a list of $i$ polynomials, where only the $i^{th}$ term
is the correct one I am looking for.

Is there a way to sieve them and thus get the desired polyomial expansion?
or, Is there an easier way to keep the term $\frac{1}{n!}$ without simplification in the
coefficient of $x^{n}?$

Comment: `SeriesCoefficient[Sec[x] + Tan[x], {x, 0, n}] // Simplify`

Comment: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/74078/taylor-series-without-expanding-factorial-in-denominator) is a similar post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a question of output formatting, then perhaps this:

```
n = 9;
Block[{x},
   x /: Power[x, k_?Positive] := Defer[x^k/k!];
   Normal@ReplacePart[#,
     3 :> Range[#[[4]], #[[4]] + Length@#[[3]] - 1]! #[[3]]]
   ] &@Series[Sec[x] + Tan[x], {x, 0, n}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Michael, definitely retrieves the Euler numbers!! Just a question, this seems specially suited for the function $\text{sec}(x)+\text{tan}(x)$ but for other functions we do not get the general form $1+a_{1}x+a_{2}\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+a_{3}\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+a_{4}\frac{x^{4}}{4!}+etc.$ Consider that our even powers are generated by sec$(x)=1+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+5\frac{x^{4}}{4!}+61\frac{x^{6}}{6!}+etc.$ whereas odd powers are generated by tan$(x)=x+2\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+16\frac{x^{5}}{5!}+etc.$ But I do not understand, why this program fails to get those series separately?

Comment: @FélixdelaFuente The 3rd part of output of `Series` is the list of coefficients.  If the last coefficient is zero, as the degree-9 coefficient of `Sec[x]` is, it is truncated.  The list of coefficients is shorter than `Range[0, n]`.  I've updated it to calculate the correct length.

Comment: It works now for sec$(n)$, but somehow for tan$(x)$ it gives "almost" the correct polynomial form, but divided by the power index: $\frac{a_n\frac{x^{n}}{n!}}{n}$. Why could this happen?

Comment: @FélixdelaFuente  Testing revealed it needed one more tweak.

Comment: Thank you, now it works perfecly with all Trig functions! It is nice  to have them with this representation.